# Basic WiFly server returning unexpected output within web client

Tags: arduino-uno

Currently trying to implement a lightweight webserver using the WiFly shield and an Arduino UNO, this is the code I have so far:

```
#include <SPI.h> 
#include <WiFly.h>
WiFlyServer server(80);

/* Function defs */
void cmd(void)  { SpiSerial.print("$$$"); }
void dhcp(void) { SpiSerial.println("SET IP DHCP 0"); }
void pass(void) { SpiSerial.println("SET WLAN PHRASE 22222222"); }
void ssid(void) { SpiSerial.println("JOIN BTHOMEHUB"); }
void port(void) { SpiSerial.println("SET IP LOCAL 80"); }
void ip(void)   { SpiSerial.println("SET IP ADDRESS 192.168.1.123"); }
void tcp(void)  { SpiSerial.println("SET IP PROTOCOL 2"); }
void boot(void) { SpiSerial.println("REBOOT"); }

/* Pointer to a handler function */
typedef void (*Handler)(void);
Handler table[8] = { cmd, dhcp, pass, ssid, port, ip, tcp, boot };

void setup() {
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  SpiSerial.begin();

  for(short x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
    table[x]();
    delay(100);
  }
}

void loop() {
  WiFlyClient client = server.available();

  if(client){
    while(client.connected()) {
      if(client.available()) {
        client.println("<HTML><BODY><H1>Hi</H1><P>This is text.</P></BODY></HTML>");
      }
    }
    delay(100);
    client.flush();
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

This compiles well, but when hitting `192.168.1.123` in my web browser I get an ever-increasing output like:

```
*HELLO*<
<
<
<
<
<
<
<
<
<
<
< (cont.)
```

Definitely not the expected html. I have been playing with this code for hours now and this is the most positive output I can get. If I do a `Serial.write(client.read())` within `if(client.available()) {` I am able to print all the request information to the serial monitor, it just seems I am perhaps sending the data in an incorrect format? Any suggestions? Cheers

**Edit**

I have updated the codebase to include the http headers,

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
client.println("Connnection: close");
client.println("");
client.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
client.println("<HTML><BODY><H1>Hi.....
```

now I get I different (similar) output, seems like it is printing the first character of each new line

```
*HELLO*H
C
C

<
<
H
C
C
```

Comment: A web server sends more than just HTML. It sends all the HTTP headers as well, which you seem to be missing.

Comment: @Majenko Added the http headers, check the edit

Comment: You still aren't outputting it right. There has to be a single blank line between the headers and the body to separate them.

Comment: @Majenko check now

Answer (score 1):

Your browser sent a HTTP GET request. You need to send a HTTP response in kind, in accordance with the protocol, for your browser to correctly interpret the data. Something like this should do:

```
  #define TIMEOUT 100
  char response[] = "<HTML><BODY><H1>Hi</H1><P>This is text.</P></BODY></HTML>";
  unsigned long lastRead;
  ...

  while (client.connected()){
    if (client.available()){
      lastRead = millis();
      while (millis() - lastRead < TIMEOUT){
        while (client.available()){
          Serial.write(client.read());
          lastRead = millis();
        }
      }
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nConnection: closed\r\n\r\n");
      client.print(response);
      break;
    }
  }
  delay(1000);
  client.stop();
```

EDIT:

It turns out that the Wifly shield sends a response status as well as "HELLO" by default. You have to disable that with a few commands:

```
set comm remote 0
set comm open 0
set comm close 0
```

This will ensure that "*HELLO*" isnt sent each time a client connection is made, though I'm not sure if this affects the default `HTTP/0.9 200 OK` response status that is always sent. You can try the sketch above with and without the response header to see what you get.

Comment: Hey, appreciate your answer -- I tried this but my browser just hangs

Comment: Weird, so with `client.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");` I get a response, but again it looks like: `*HELLO*H
S
C5
C

<
<H
S
C5
C`

Comment: the serial monitor looks good: `GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.123
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
` but the browser still hangs

Comment: With the timer it seems to hang regardless of the `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and yeah the browser renders the html fine :j

Comment: @WilliamPaul How about this? I changed the timeout and the print()s

Comment: Okay, so the timer still causes the browser to hang, but without that and with the updated http header I get: `*HELLO*S
H
<H
<H
<H
<H
<H` (more than one char on a line)

Comment: @WilliamPaul I've edited the answer